# How can I synchronize a for loop?

Tags: java, multithreading

The task is:

> Synchronize the pass through of the list, with the auto objects on the list object. This must be done because there is a possibility that in parallel another thread could insert items into the list

My code:

```
ArrayList<Cars> temporary = new ArrayList<Cars>();
synchronized(temporary){
    for (Cars i : temporary) {...}
}
```

Did I synchronize that correct?

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. (1) you said, `synchronized(temporary)` where the `temporary` object can not possibly be accessed by any other thread, and (2) you said `for (Cars i : temporary) {...}` where `temporary` can not possibly contain any `Cars`.

Comment: puuuh. I am a very noob in this. How would be that correct?

Comment: You are asking about a list with "auto objects on the list," but your example doesn't show any such list. It only shows you creating a new _empty_ list. You are asking about a list that is shared by more than one thread, but your code doesn't show the list being shared. Where is the rest of your code? It's hard for anybody to answer questions about code that you haven't showed to them.

Comment: That is the problem. I dont know in which other line the code use again the list. (We have 7000 lines of code (a big project)). Yes of course this list looks empty because i fill the list in Task 8, now we are in Task 5. So in this moment the list looks empty, but in task 8 we normally fill the list. And then the list is not empty My task here is it to synchronized the the pass through the list for the case, that in a other line, which I dont know, a thread wants to use the list also.

Comment: Impossible to give a specific answer to such a vague question, but _in general,_ you need some object to use as a "lock," You need to ensure that every bit of code that accesses the list is inside a `synchronized(lock)` statement, and you need to make sure that `lock` refers to the same object in every case. If you want to use the list itself as the lock object (e.g., like in your example), that will work, and it's easy to do, but some day, if you study advanced software engineering, you may learn of subtle down-sides of using a public data structure as its own "lock."

Comment: Java probably does optimalisation and kick off this synchronized block because this is completely thread safety operation in this case

Comment: Thank you also for the tipps how to ask @cliff